# how to show a view with one to many relations

Tags: views

I am using Entity Reference, what would be the best way to show the parent entity on the top (4 columns ) and then the children entities in horizontal rows below? 
Can Display suite be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Display Suite would work for this. With the right modules and configuration, you may not even need to create a View.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did it with display suite without a view, by fiddling with the custom fields that you can add with display suite